# How to add missing SNAPSHOT dependency to Heroku?

Tags: scala, github, heroku, playframework, sbt

I have a Scala Play 2.7.x application which I deploy to Heroku. However, the build fails due to a missing dependency `"com.github.tototoshi" %% "play-joda-routes-binder" % "1.3.1-SNAPSHOT"` and that's correct because this one I built locally. How do I make this missing dependency available to Heroku?

The dependency I need is this one `https://github.com/tototoshi/play-joda-routes-binder` but it had a bug which I fixed here `https://github.com/tototoshi/play-joda-routes-binder/pull/6`. However, the author of that project seems afk for several months now. I can build my PR locally but how do I add it to Heroku for my project to work?

Comment: I suggest you to deploy your version to maven central / jfrog /sonatype or something alike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the compiled jar into a subfolder in the project for example: `/lib`. Sbt will automatically look for jars in this directory. If you want to configure it as something else you can define the key unmanagedBase:

```
unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / "custom_lib"
```

There's more documentation about sbt lib management here: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Dependencies.html.

Also playframework documents this, but it's basically the same:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.1/SBTDependencies

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to not use the automatic deployment with connection to Github but rather the SBT Heroku CLI and then build / deploy locally and simply upload the binary artifacts to Heroku like so:

```
sbt stage deployHeroku
heroku open --app myapp
```

after adding the following two entries into the `project/plugins.sbt` file (latest versions as of today):

```
addSbtPlugin("com.heroku" % "sbt-heroku" % "2.1.2")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.4.1")
```